# Search by special characters

Tags: php, mysql, sql

In our table contains column named as description.

The description column contains following values.

`test`,`%test`,`test%`.

If I give `%test` as input of search string ,  then it give `"test","%test","test%"` as result. But I want only `"%test"` as result.

Comment: Post the query you're using in your question. How can anyone help you if you don't give any information?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

% is a special character and needs to be escaped (http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/string-literals.html)

Try "\%test"

Snippet:

```
select description from tablename where decription like '\%test'
```

Comment: Now I used dynamic LIKE string. So I have used addcslahes(mysql_real_escape_string("input_string",'%?*..')).

Comment: good to hear!! Would you be so kind as to accept my answer? (and thanks to Rat-a-tat-a-tat Ratatouille for the snippet)!